# How to document nested typescript interfaces for VS Code hints

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am struggling to write a types documentation for a module I'm working on and to get VSCode to show things in hover / intellisense.

Take this example:

```
/**
 * @description a complex object
 * @property prop1 - a string 
 * @property prop2 - a number argument
 */
interface myObj {
    /** string prop1 */
    prop1: string;
    prop2?: number;
    [key: string]: any
}

interface myfunc {

    /**
     * @description method description
     * @argument foo The first argument
     * @argument {myObj} bar
     */
    some_method: (
        /** simple string argument */
        foo : string,
        /** how to get this to display the description above?  */
        bar : myObj
    ) => void
}
```

What's working:

1. Hovering over `some_method` in either `.js` or `.ts` I get the three line description & arg comments
2. `CTRL` + `SHFIT` + `SPACE` while over the first argument gives me the `simple string argument` help
3. Opening an Object as the second argument and hitting `CTRL` + `SPACE` suggests `prop1` and `prop2`
4. Hovering over `prop1` inside the second argument gives me `string prop1`

What isn't working:

The problem I'm having is how do I get the whole description block for `myObj` displayed when I hit `CTRL` + `SHFIT` + `SPACE` while inside the object of the second argument? It would be super helpful for this kind of argument where there are some predefined properties like `prop1` and `prop2` but it also allows the user to add any other keys, to have the markdown supported description of `myObj` displayed.

The moment I add any `@` decorators in the comment line above `bar : myObj` in the `myfunc` interface VS Code doesn't display anything anymore. And if I want to reuse the `myObj` interface in other methods, it of course doesn't make sense to use that inline documenting style like `simple string argument` repeatedly in the code (and it doesn't solve the one line, no markdown problem either).

Comment: Might be a better choice to open an issue on VSCode or the TypeScript repo? I'm not too sure which one but there's little we can do here.

Comment: that depends on whether it is a VS Code issue or whether I have mistakes in the way either the comments are written. I am not very familiar with creating a types file or JSDoc, so that's a very real possibility